# Erlang; OTP application "app.config"

Tags: erlang

I have an OTP application. So far, I have two configuration files: `rebar.config` and `config/vm.args`, the latter of which is referenced in the former: `{vm_args, "config/vm.args"}`.

In the lager documentation: https://github.com/erlang-lager/lager
There is mention of another configuration file: `app.config`. Where does this file go and how do I reference it from my rebar config? In /src or at the root of the application? I ask because I tried adding that `lager` section in my `rebar.config` and that didn't do anything: lager is still operating with the defaults. So I probably need this `app.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK figured this out. In Rebar you can specify `sys.config`: https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases

So I have a new file `config/sys.config` and my relx section now reads:

```
{relx, [
    {release,
        {myapp,"3.4.1"},
        [myapp]
    },
    %{extend_start_script,true},
    %
    %for the following two fancyiness see https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases
    %Supply our own vm.args
    {vm_args, "config/vm.args"},
    %supply our own application configuration
    {sys_config, "config/sys.config"}
   ]}.
```